# php: users timezone changes every time tzdata is updated

Tags: php, timezone

We are saving the timezone for each user as the ID of that timezone.

The problem is, that every time that the tzdata package is updated, there are changes in the IDs, and this changes the users saved timezones.

What way is there to ensure that the users saved timezones will always remain consistent?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "ID" exactly, can you make an example?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the problem was that the programmer thought it would be easier to treat the list of available timezones as a fixed list, and store the users' own timezones as the timezones positions in the list.

i.e., if Europe/Berlin used to be in position 100 in the list of timezones, then this is the number that would have been stored for the users in the DB. But if the package tzdata was updated with new timezones, then in position 100 you would fine Europe/Belgrade, and the users would effectively have wrong timezones defined to them.

The solution is to convert all old ID numbers that are stored to the relevant true string that appears as a timezone. This way, when tzdata is next being updated, the users will retain their current timezone.